# Cannot build image with podman

Tags: python-3.x, podman

I'm trying podman for the first time, and I'm failing to build my image. I've run:

```
podman machine init
podman machine start
podman build -t myimage .
```

The dockerfile is fairly simple and starts with:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster AS build
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
[1/2] STEP 1/11: FROM python:3.8-buster AS build
Resolved "python" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/python:3.8-buster...
Error: error creating build container: initializing source docker://python:3.8-buster: pinging 
container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Your DNS lookup is failing. Are you on a Mac or Windows and running podman inside a VM? I'm guessing it's an issue with the name lookup from that VM. On a linux machine myself, so can't help you with the VM setup I'm afraid, but that is wehre to look.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. Yes, I am on Windows, and have podman 4.2.1 which runs inside WSL

Comment: did you solve it? I can of have a similar issue atm